# fullwidth drop down background navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to have a navigation, which has a fullwidth background.
When hovering a link, not only the text-links should drop down but also a fullwidth (of the navigation) background should slide down as well.

Does anybody have an idea?

The code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/u9r8wc6b/

```
    <div class="navigation" id="fdw">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a>

                        <ul style="display: none;" class="sub_menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Home Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home Responsive</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">portfolio</a>
                    <ul style="display: none;" class="sub_menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio 3 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio 4 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio Single</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

I added a image to make it more clear:

http://s14.directupload.net/images/141017/9b6443c4.jpg

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: You could animate the height of the background. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

I need some more explanation please. If you just want to give the background to the dropdown even after it slide down then you can use css like this.  background:red.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply! I updated the code at jsfiddle. Now you can see a red background at the sub-menu. My problem: I want to have the red background at 100% width of the menu. Thanks in advance

Comment: nothing is updated in fiddle. I am unable to see a red background

Comment: Anyways please try this one. this will make background red at 100% width.                                                         select{
      background-color:red !important;
}

Comment: I didn't work. I tried to add it at several positions. You mean, that I should add !important at the background right?

Comment: If you just want to set background and it is not working then set it !important. (i.e. select{background: red !important} OR  select{background-color: red !important}) I hope this will work for you. If worked then please up my answer and accept as answer :)

Comment: Actually it isn't that easy. To make clear what I want, here are two pictures: What it is now: [link](http://s14.directupload.net/images/141017/4z3jvcsw.jpg) What it should look like: [link](http://s14.directupload.net/images/141017/c8jmcuia.jpg) Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alex give me your html and css. I don't think it is hard to implement.